# Не работает NOT IN для массива

Tags: mysql

Почему так запрос исключает нормально:

```
SELECT tasks.tid FROM `tasks`
 WHERE `turl_full` NOT IN (SELECT `tdurl` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `tduid` = '12561')
 ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

а так, ничего не исключает:

```
$array = array();
$a = $db->query("SELECT `tdurl` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `tduid` = '12561'");

while($b = $db->fetch($a)) {
 $array[] = $b['tdurl'];
}

$array = implode(',', $array);

$db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks`
 WHERE `turl_full` NOT IN ('".$array."')
 ORDER BY `tamount` DESC");
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: вы выполняете конкатенацию строки с массивом? может стоит тогда сделать так?

    $db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `turl_full` NOT IN ('" . implode("','", $array) . "') ORDER BY `tamount` DESC");

Comment: @vanchester, так и есть, просто забыл в тексте об этом написать. Отредактировал, посмотрите.

Comment: @ModaL, а что на счет кавычек? посмотрите, как записал я. у вас в результате в запросе будет что-то типа NOT IN ('1,2,3,4')

Comment: @vanchester, отлично! Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, помечу, что он верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выполняете конкатенацию строки с массивом. Исправьте запрос на

```
$db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `turl_full` NOT IN ('" . implode("','", $array) . "') ORDER BY `tamount` DESC");
```

Comment: @vanchester, спасибо!